having issue in deploing dotnet core api on azure app service as virtual application using github workflow without publish profile
I'm trying to deploy my api applications on azure app services as virtual application (/api/service1/) using GitHub workflows. I was able to deploy but other virtual applications are getting deleted when I see in scm portal. How can I clean only the target virtual application directory before deploying latest version.
if I set clean argument as true then it is clearing wwwroot directory and all other virtual applications directories are deleting.
If I set clean argument as false then wwwroot directories are not getting deleted but in virtual application old binaries(dlls) exists.
Here is my workflow file.
deploy:
    if: ${{ github.ref == inputs.branch_name }}
    name: Deploying app on Azure
    runs-on: [self-hosted-linux]
    needs: [publish_artifacts]
    environment:
      name: ${{ inputs.environment_name }}
    steps:
      - name: Install az cli
        uses: elstudio/action-install-azure-cli@v1

      # authenticate to azure
      - name: "Az CLI login"
        uses: azure/login@v1.5.1
        with:
          creds: '{"clientId":"${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}","clientSecret":"${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET }}","subscriptionId":"${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}","tenantId":"${{ env.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}"}'

      - name: Download published artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: dev-artifact

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: "${{ inputs.azure_app_name }}"
          package: ${{ github.WORKSPACE }}
          target-path: ${{ inputs.virtual_app_path}}
          clean: true 

if I set clean argument as true then it is clearing wwwroot directory and all other virtual applications directories are deleting.
If I set clean argument as false then wwwroot directories are not getting deleted but in virtual application old binaries(dlls) exists.
I'm expecting to delete files only within specific targeted virtual directory and not to delete any of other virtual directory exists in wwwroot folder.

can you share your github repo if possible ?

I created a sample ASP. NET Core Web Api with Virtual directories in it and able to delete specific directory files via GitHub actions.

I've added the below code to my workflow to delete the required virtual directory from wwwroot folder.
I've referred this doc for curl command.

- name: Delete files from /api2 directory using Kudu API
run: |
curl -X DELETE "https://linuxvirtual-dqa2hggacehwggdt.scm.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/api2/?recursive=true" \
-H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n ${{ secrets.KUDU_USERNAME }}:${{ secrets.KUDU_PASSWORD }} | base64)" \
-v \
--write-out "%{http_code}" \
--output /dev/null


 ?recursive=true this is a query that tells the KUDU API to delete the directory and its contents.

My complete workflow file

Set clean to false as this allows to delete only the specific directory, without removing other files or directories.

name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - linuxvirtual
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.x'
      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release
      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{ github.workspace }}/myapp
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{ github.workspace }}/myapp
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write 
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app    
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_<client-id> }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_<tenant-id>}}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_<subscription-id> }}
      - name: Debug connectivity to Kudu
        run: |
          nslookup linuxvirtual-dqa2hggacehwggdt.scm.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net
          curl -v https://linuxvirtual-dqa2hggacehwggdt.scm.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net
      - name: Delete files from /api2 directory using Kudu API
        run: |
          curl -X DELETE "https://linuxvirtual-dqa2hggacehwggdt.scm.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/api2/?recursive=true" \
          -H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n ${{ secrets.KUDU_USERNAME }}:${{ secrets.KUDU_PASSWORD }} | base64)" \
          -v \
          --write-out "%{http_code}" \
          --output /dev/null

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'linuxvirtual'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          clean : false


Here, you can see that I first deployed the app at 4:07:52 PM.


After modifying my workflow file and configuring the delete command, the old files were removed and replaced with new ones.

You can see the updated files with the latest modification date.



